# Show that a given estimator is biased and consistent

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, unbiased-estimator, consistency

Let the model be $\log(W) = a + bX + U$ where $E(U) = 0$. We are allowed to assume that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,U) = 0$, and want to show $e^{xb^\text{ols}}$-1 is a consistent estimator for $e^{xb}$-1 and it is a biased estimator for $e^{xb}$-1. We can derive that $b^\text{ols} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2}$, where $Y_i = \log(W_i)$.

Since $y = e^x$ is a convex function than $E(e^{xb^{ols}}-1) \ge e^{E(x)b^{ols}}-1$, but where do I go from here?

Comment: It is simpler than that. For biasedness, use Jensen's inequality. For consistency, the magical property of probability limits related to functions of random variables (hint: a property that unfortunately does not characterize also the expected value) is what you need.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos am I applying the inequality right?

Comment: The function $e^z$ is a strictly convex function in its argument ($z$), whatever this argument is (a scalar, or a function...) So 

$$E(e^{x\hat b}-1) > e^{E(x\hat b)}-1$$ And to what $E(x\hat b)$ is equal to?

Comment: $Xb^{ols} = Y_i$ we can see that if we multiply the sum by $X_i - \bar X$ so then $E(xb^{ols}) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(Y_i)=n* \bar Y$?

Comment: $Xb^{ols} = Y_i -\hat u$

Comment: I made a mistake above, you are correct, there's not summation anymore, so then $Xb^{ols} = Y_i - u_i = a +bX_i$, hence $E(Xb^{ols}) = a + bE(X)?$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11450/discussion-between-user77404-and-alecos-papadopoulos)